# Why won't it let me get a steward?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I bought property, finished and furnished my home but the dialogue for gaining a steward hasn't appeared for either one of my companions who stay at my home, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

not every follower or person can be a steward, for a full list go [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Steward_(Hearthfire))

> Several followers are available to serve as steward. They can only be appointed to three homesteads in Skyrim:

General companions:

```
Adelaisa Vendicci
Annekke Crag-Jumper
Eola
Erik the Slayer
Faendal
Ghorbash the Iron Hand
Golldir
Illia
Lob
Marcurio
Ogol
Roggi Knot-Beard
Sven
Talvas Fathryon DR
Uthgerd the Unbroken
Belrand
```

Followers

```
Aela the Huntress
Njada Stonearm
Ria
Vilkas
```

Dawnguard

```
Aela the Huntress
Njada Stonearm
Ria
Vilkas
```

College mages

```
Brelyna Maryon
Onmund
```

Housecarls

```
Calder
Gregor
Iona
Jordis the Sword-Maiden
Lydia
Rayya
Valdimar
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, didn't have access to internet, i have added the full list